# How to publishing an angular2 directives

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, bower, directive

I have written an angular2 directive called ng2-clearfix. The typescript code itself is ready, it's tested and works just fine.

I now want to publish the directive on github so others can use it as well, i had a few questions while doing that:

- How should i serve the file? Like should i provide ng2-clearfix.js file or should i just leave ng2-clearfix.ts and let the user compile typescript to javascript.

  - How should i manage dependancies for ng2-clearfix itself. I want to publish it on both npm and bower. i think using bower for my own dependency management will be a problem because the developer using ng2-clearfix may or may not be using bower.

Thanks for you time.

Also if you know a boilerplate for angular2 directive please let me know, that would make tasks easier.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can start by using this amazing tool [generator-angular2-library](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library)

Iv'e used it recently for a library I wrote for Ionic2, and it really saved me some time.

It is a pretty simple Yeoman generator that produces you a skeleton for your library.
Then, after you finish organizing your app, you can publish it to [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages).

Since Angular 2 uses Typescript, all the files should eventually be transpiled to javascript. 
The basic idea is to keep all the source files in your repository, compile the files and publish them to npm under the right version. You should not commit the compiled files to the repository.

Your'e welcome to look at the library I wrote to see how things basically work: https://github.com/kadoshms/ionic2-autocomplete